# Можно ли использовать lazy.fetch при entitymanager + jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Бьюсь над ошибкой could not initialize - no proxy уже долгое время, с Eager.Fetch все прекрасно работает. Поэтому закрался такой вопрос.

**Upd.**
Я обращаюсь в контроллере к методу данного сервиса

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;


@Override
public List<User> getAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
}
```

Вот мой entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_city")
private City city;

...

}
```

Выдает ошибку что не может инициализировать city - no Proxy.

Comment: Можно. Используйте наздоровье

Comment: @Sergey, я добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста, может что-то подскажите. Уже неделю бьюсь(

Comment: Никогда бы даже не подумал для отношения типа Вашего city, прописывать какой-либо fetch: ни lazy, ни eager. И вообще он удивительным образом везде где надо lazy по-умолчанию

Comment: Вообще-то кое-кто утверждает, что можно так делать, но jpa провайдер не обязан реально поддерживать lazy в данном случае. Но и ошибок вроде не должен показывать. Наверно это глюк

Comment: При Lazy загрузке entityManager возвращает proxy. Если entityManager закрылся, то после обращению к полю, которое пометили Lazy, вы получите ошибку. Например, вот здесь:
        Guide guide = entityManager.find(Guide.class, 1L);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    
        Set<Student> students = guide.getStudents();

Возможно, в этом дело?